# Anonymous Tables Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I was curious about the performance impact of **Anonymous Table** (*don't know if it's the right term or not*) on an SQL query. Suppose I have a situation like below.

A table which has columns including a PK column

```
create table tab1 (id int identity(1, 1) primary key,
                   name varchar(100),
                   addedOn datetime);
```

Which has values in it.

```
insert into tab1 (name, addedOn)
select 'Fname1 Lname1', DATEADD(month, -10, getdate()) union
select 'Fname2 Lname2', DATEADD(month, -9, getdate()) union
select 'Fname3 Lname3', DATEADD(month, -8, getdate()) union
select 'Fname4 Lname4', DATEADD(month, -7, getdate()) union
select 'Fname5 Lname5', DATEADD(month, -6, getdate()) union
select 'Fname6 Lname6', DATEADD(month, -5, getdate())
```

And I have a query to select data from it.

```
select * from
(
    select  
            id,
            Fname = SUBSTRING(name, 1, charindex(' ', name) - 1),
            Lname = SUBSTRING(name, charindex(' ', name) + 1, 100),
            addedOn = convert(date, addedOn)
    from    tab1
) as TAB
where TAB.Fname = 'Fname' and TAB.Lname = 'Lname'
```

Now, by **Anonymous Table** I'm referring to `TAB` in above query. I'm using that name as this subquery's table can be used very much like a table in select statements, I use it very often when some formatting needs to be done and I don't want to write that formatting again & again. As you can see an alternative for above query can be this:

```
select  
        id,
        Fname = SUBSTRING(name, 1, charindex(' ', name) - 1),
        Lname = SUBSTRING(name, charindex(' ', name) + 1, 100),
        addedOn = convert(date, addedOn)
from    tab1
where   SUBSTRING(name, 1, charindex(' ', name) - 1) = 'Fname' and 
        SUBSTRING(name, charindex(' ', name) + 1, 100) = 'Lname'
```

But it has ugly formatting written twice. Till now this syntax is looking pretty life saver but I just want to be sure about it, and some expert opinion would be great to know:

1. Where does this Anonymous Table gets stored in memory, if they do get stored at all.
2. Will these Anonymous Table give me all the benefits of Indexes which a normal table does (*tables which are being used inside subquery*)?
3. I have seen execution plan of this particular query used in question, and they were identical. But will the result remain same when Anonymous Table have multiple tables joined inside subquery?

I'm using SQL server 2012

Comment: They are called derived table. 2) In your particular case `SUBSTRING(name, 1, charindex(' ', name) - 1) = 'Fname'` is not SARGable so query optimizer cannot use index on column name if exists any

Comment: Also called an "inline view".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you call "anonymous tables" are either called derived tables or subqueries.

It sounds like you want a view:

```
create view v_tab1 as
    select  id,
            Fname = SUBSTRING(name, 1, charindex(' ', name) - 1),
            Lname = SUBSTRING(name, charindex(' ', name) + 1, 100),
            addedOn = convert(date, addedOn)
    from    tab1;
```

When you have done this, you can reference the view anywhere.

Alternative, you can add the computed values directly into the table definition:

```
alter tab1 add Fname as ( SUBSTRING(name, 1, charindex(' ', name) - 1) );
alter tab1 add Lname as ( SUBSTRING(name, charindex(' ', name) + 1, 100) );
alter tab1 add addedOn as (convert(date, addedOn) );
```

Then, the `fname`, `lname`, and `addedon` will act as columns in the table, and be automatically updated when the table changes.